# can you please tell why there is no output while running

Tags: java, string, debugging

I am trying to solve https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW010 problem.
I wrote 
`

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t>0){
            String s=sc.next();
            if(s=="b" || s=="B"){
                System.out.println("BattleShip");
            }
            else if(s=="c" || s=="C"){
                System.out.println("Cruiser");
            }
            else if(s=="d" || s=="D"){
                System.out.println("Destroyer");
            }
            else if(s=="f" || s=="F"){
                System.out.println("Frigate");
            }
            t--;
        }
    }
```

` 
There is no mistake in terms of syntax. Please help me what is mistake

Comment: comparing String with `==` must be replaced with `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: Use String equals

Comment: For next time : your title should resume your problem and be specific, here the title should be used for thousands of posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all your `==` comparisons for String like this:

```
String s=sc.next();
if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("b") {
    System.out.println("BattleShip");
}
// ... etc.
```

Comment: Thank you! can you explain why not to use == ? What is problem in it?

Comment: @Sachin `==` is used to check the reference or memory address of the objects to check whether they point to the same location or not. Since `String` is non-primitive `equals()` method is used to compare the contents of the `String`. So in your case you are trying to match `String s` have the desired character (b or B in your case). So to check that you have to use the `equals()` method. You can refer for more [here](https://www.java67.com/2012/11/difference-between-operator-and-equals-method-in.html)